# Error:Cannot find symbol.. in My Java Program

Tags: java, string, find, symbols

This is my whole code
Getting the following error in command prompt.Please Help me to solve it, a beginner here.

```
"Student.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
                        s[i].Student();
                            ^
  symbol:   method Student()
  location: class Student
1 error"

    import java.util.*;

public class Student
{
    int roll;
    String name=new String();


    Student()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Name");
        name=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Roll No");
        roll=sc.nextInt();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name:"+name+" "+"Roll Number:"+roll ;
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n,i;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        Student s[]=new Student[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=new Student();
            s[i].Student();
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with - `s[i].Student();`?

Comment: What are you going to do while calling `s[i].Student();` ?
If you want to call the constructor, then you don't need it, because you already called it in `s[i]=new Student();`

Comment: `Student()` is a constructor, not a function that you can call like that.

Comment: calling a user defined constructor Student.. Dont know if it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 35 you are correctly instantiating a class with the constructor,

```
s[i]=new Student();
```

On line 36 you're incorrectly (and for no apparent logical reason?) calling a constructor like a method. Remove this line:

```
s[i].Student();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need that line:
`s[i].Student();`

The `Student()` constructor is called when you write `new Student()`.

[Read this about constructors in Java.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: what if i want to make the Constructor overload to do the job of scanning things like above ? Will deleting s[i].student(); work ?

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need a class Main, take your method main and put it inside your class Student, remove this line:

s[i].Student();

And the program runs fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling the constructor like `s[i].Student()` which is incorrect.

Java will assume that Student() is a method and not a constructor. Since you don't have a method normal Student() method in your class, for sure, it will not be found.

Remember, constructor is not just a plain method. It's a special method to instantiate objects.